# Is there a way to add the number of outputs from a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, rstudio

I inserted a for loop:

```
for(j in 2:1036) {
  nMatchingLoci = 0
  for(i in 1:1) {
    if(sampGeno[1,i]==FGMMdata[1,i,j] && sampGeno[2,i]==FGMMdata[2,i,j]) {
      nMatchingLoci = nMatchingLoci + 1
    }
  }

  if(nMatchingLoci==1) {
    print(paste("!!! 1 locus match with entry number", j))
 }
  }
```

And my output is just a list of profiles. How do I add how many are there?

The list looks like this in my console:

```
[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 4"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 7"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 24"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 44"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 51"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 53"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 58"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 63"

[1] "!!! 1 locus match with entry number 72"
```

and so on...

Comment: Your for loop over i doesn't do anything aside from setting the value of i equal to 1. Either you don't need that for loop and need to just set i equal to 1, or you have a mistake with the sequence.

Also, presuming your for loop over i runs for (lets say) i in 1:1035 you now would have the possibility that a match will be found more than once, making nMatchingLoci greater than 1 which will then fail the if statement declaring that you have a match.

Answer (score 0):

Before the for loop create a variable with a value of 0 (x=0). Then inside the second if statement add 
 x=x+1

Then after running the for loop just print the value of x. That's your count.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a vector or a list to store the indexes of your "locus matches", then after your loops finish you can count the entries.

Personally I would use a list since its more versatile (but its a little more finicky to work with)

```
## Preallocate list
matchList <- vector("list",1036)

for(j in 2:1036) {
  for(i in 1:1) {
    if(sampGeno[1,i]==FGMMdata[1,i,j] && sampGeno[2,i]==FGMMdata[2,i,j]) {
      matchList[[j]] <- c(matchList[[j]],i)
    }
  }
} 

## indexes i where match was found for j=73
matchList[[73]]

## Number of matches for each j index
lengths(matchList)

## Total number of matches
sum(lengths(matchList))
```

As I said in my comment, I'm working under the assumption that the for loop over i is over a sequence other than 1:1.

Comment: "We made our way into the second Circle, here live the gluttons". Alas and alack, ye have stumbled into Chapter 2 of [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#chapter.2) by growing objects.